# How to read all attribute values in a VBA LDAP query?

Tags: vba, ldap

I'm doing some development work and need to see what data is stored in Active Directory in order to figure out which fields are being used and may contain information that will be useful.  I have a method of pulling all of the mandatory property field names, and of pulling the data with LDAP if I know what the field names are, but what I can't figure out is how to do it dynamically.  Here's my code:

```
Function LDAPdump()
    Dim objSysInfo As Object
    Dim objSchema As Object
    Dim objRecordset As Object
    Dim objConnection As Object
    Dim objCommand As Object
    Dim objUser As Object
    Dim objLUser As Object
    Dim dname As String
    Dim DLoc As Integer
    Dim ADaddress As String
    Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set objSchema = GetObject("LDAP://schema/user")
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
    dname = objUser.distinguishedName
    DLoc = InStr(dname, "DC=")
    ADaddress = Right(dname, Len(dname) - DLoc + 1)
    Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
    Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
    objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1
    objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE
    objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM 'LDAP://" & ADaddress & "' WHERE objectCategory='user' AND cn='" & objUser.CN & "'"
    Set objRecordset = objCommand.Execute
    If objRecordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "no data"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set objLUser = GetObject(objRecordset.Fields("ADsPath").Value)
    'print all mandatory property field names
    For Each strAttribute In objSchema.MandatoryProperties
        Debug.Print strAttribute & ": " & objLUser(CStr(strAttribute)).Value
    Next
End Function
```

The spot that's specifically giving me issues is pulling the `objLUser` attribute value.  For example, when I run this code the first attribute that comes up is `cn`.  If I specifically write `Debug.Print strAttribute & ": " & objLUser.cn` I get `cn: Chaosbydesign` back in the immediate window, but when I try to dynamically get it in the For loop, I get back "The directory property cannot be found in the cache."  Looking at objUser or objLUser in the Locals window doesn't provide any hints to a solution because it just says `<No Variables>` when expanded, even though I can go into the immediate window and type in `? objLUser.cn/mail/displayname` and get my common name, email and display name back.

I have a workaround for this that involves a bit of shenanigans with a text file and Excel to basically write out the `Debug.Print` line for every single attribute, so this problem itself isn't a show stopper, more just an annoyance that I'd like to figure out.